# Wikitude license using wikitude studio

Tags: wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I had applied for a educational license for android sdk in wikitude. Can I use this license for wikitude studio? Or I must pay for another license for the wikitude studio?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Wikitude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Wikitude Studio with the same account. The SDK license is just to use Wikitude SDK in your app of your chosen platform.

For more information, send an e-mail to the Wikitude customer support.